# Subversion merge behavior

Tags: svn, svn-merge

I have created a quick example to demonstrate my question. From the log below you will see following:

1. r1 - created trunk
2. r2 - created branches
3. r3 - added foo.txt into trunk
4. r4 - created QA branch
5. r5 - created UK branch
6. r6 - created TEAM branch
7. r7 - updated foo.txt and added bar on TEAM branch
8. r8 - merged TEAM into QA
9. r9 - merged QA into trunk

So my question is when I try to do,
svn merge -r9:HEAD ^/trunk 
from within UK directory I don't get the r9 changes is this the expected behavior?

```
svn log -v -g ^/
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r9 | anazimok | 2012-03-15 21:16:37 -0400 (Thu, 15 Mar 2012) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   M /trunk
   A /trunk/bar (from /branches/QA/bar:8)
   M /trunk/foo.txt

merged QA into trunk
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r8 | anazimok | 2012-03-15 21:16:34 -0400 (Thu, 15 Mar 2012) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   M /branches/QA
   A /branches/QA/bar (from /branches/TEAM/bar:7)
   M /branches/QA/foo.txt
Merged via: r9

merged team into QA
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r7 | anazimok | 2012-03-15 21:16:32 -0400 (Thu, 15 Mar 2012) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /branches/TEAM/bar
   M /branches/TEAM/foo.txt
Merged via: r9, r8

updated on team branch
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r7 | anazimok | 2012-03-15 21:16:32 -0400 (Thu, 15 Mar 2012) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /branches/TEAM/bar
   M /branches/TEAM/foo.txt
Merged via: r9

updated on team branch
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r8 | anazimok | 2012-03-15 21:16:34 -0400 (Thu, 15 Mar 2012) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   M /branches/QA
   A /branches/QA/bar (from /branches/TEAM/bar:7)
   M /branches/QA/foo.txt

merged team into QA
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r7 | anazimok | 2012-03-15 21:16:32 -0400 (Thu, 15 Mar 2012) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /branches/TEAM/bar
   M /branches/TEAM/foo.txt
Merged via: r8

updated on team branch
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r7 | anazimok | 2012-03-15 21:16:32 -0400 (Thu, 15 Mar 2012) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /branches/TEAM/bar
   M /branches/TEAM/foo.txt

updated on team branch
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r6 | anazimok | 2012-03-15 21:16:29 -0400 (Thu, 15 Mar 2012) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /branches/TEAM (from /branches/QA:5)

created team
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r5 | anazimok | 2012-03-15 21:16:29 -0400 (Thu, 15 Mar 2012) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /branches/UK (from /trunk:4)

created UK
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r4 | anazimok | 2012-03-15 21:16:29 -0400 (Thu, 15 Mar 2012) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /branches/QA (from /trunk:3)

created QA
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r3 | anazimok | 2012-03-15 21:16:28 -0400 (Thu, 15 Mar 2012) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /trunk/foo.txt

initial commit
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r2 | anazimok | 2012-03-15 21:16:27 -0400 (Thu, 15 Mar 2012) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /branches

created branches
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1 | anazimok | 2012-03-15 21:16:27 -0400 (Thu, 15 Mar 2012) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /trunk

created trunk
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify one revision less than your intended ones, so try

```
svn merge -r8:HEAD ^/trunk
```

Answer (score 1):

You can omit merge-range in your simple case. But andreas is perfectly correct: **range is not inclusive** for start-border